# Submitting form to scrape data from a jobs board

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to write a script that gets job details from a specific [website](https://caterpillar.taleo.net/careersection/cat+external+cs/jobsearch.ftl).  The html code appears to be different when I view from Source Code (command-option-U) vs Developer Tools (command-option-I) in Google Chrome. Developer Tools has the actual details I can parse in HTML.

One example of what I am after is found in the first job posting from the website:

> Canada-Alberta-Fort McMurray, Canada-Alberta-Edmonton

I know that I need to submit a form using POST, but beyond that I am having trouble getting the html code found in Developer Tools but absent in my request.

```
import requests
url='https://caterpillar.taleo.net/careersection/cat+external+cs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&portal=4140124208&src=CWS-10005'
r = requests.post(url, data={'dropListSize': 100})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
html=r.text
```

I have also tried similar strategies using mechanize

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)

for f in br.forms():
    print f

br.select_form('ftlform')
br.form["dropListSize"] = ["100"]
br.submit()
html=br.response().read()
```

A related question is how I would get to the next page, but I feel like I might be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an XHR POST request sent to the `https://caterpillar.taleo.net/careersection/cat+external+cs/jobsearch.ajax` endpoint that contains all the search results in the response. You can either try simulating it (which I suspect is not going to be fun judging by the number of parameters and response format), or you can load the page in a real browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), let the browser load the page and don't worry about how the search results are delivered.

Working example using `selenium` + [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) headless browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://caterpillar.taleo.net/careersection/cat+external+cs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&portal=4140124208&src=CWS-10005'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.contentlist")))

for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.ftlrow"):
    title = row.find_element_by_css_selector(".titlelink a").text
    print(title)

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
Sales accountant
Manufacturing Project Engineer
Staff Accountant - Accountable
Hydraulic Cylinder Design Engineer
Engineering Supervisor(Hydraulic Cylinder)
Design Engineer
Senior Design Engineer
Senior Engineer
Senior Design Engineer
Dealer Solution Network (DSN) Analyst
```